# Integration of Salesforce with JQuery Mobile

Tags: apex, visualforce, jquery, jquerymobile

I have created a visualforce page along with the controller. In the page I have created a JQuery Mobile popup which appears on the click of a button. The popup consists of another button which is supposed to update a custom object field, but, I am not sure how to proceed.

Accept invitation

```
        <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup">
              <p>These are the terms and conditions of viewing the publication.
              </p>
              <form>
                  <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"> I agree</input></label>


                    <input type="button" id="Submit" value="Submit"></input>


                    <input type="reset" value="Cancel"></input>
              </form>
        </div>
```

I am very new to salesforce. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Create a method in your controller that updates the custom object field, then in your Visualforce page create an [ActionFunction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) to call with jQuery.

Example of the code you might use in the page:

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!controllerMethodThatUpdatesField}" name="acceptTermsAndConditions" />

<script>
  $('input#Submit').click(acceptTermsAndConditions);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rob I have written the following code, which is not working and I am not sure how to proceed.
public class Publication_Tab_Controller{
    public list  pub {get;set;}
    public Publication_Tab_Controller() {

```
String searchquery='select name,id from publication__c';  
pub= Database.query(searchquery); 
}
public Publication_Tab_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
}
public String tabOpt {get;set;}
public void switch()
{
    tabOpt='Review';
} 
@RemoteAction
public static void update_publication(publication__c publication)
{
System.debug('Check');
    publication.AcceptInvitation__c='Accepted';
    update publication;
}
```

}
Apex Page Code:

{!a.Name}

```
     <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">Accept invitation</a>
        <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup">
              <p>These are the terms and conditions of viewing the publication.
              </p>
              <form>
                  <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"> I agree</input></label>


                    <input type="button" id="Submit" value="Submit"></input>


                    <input type="reset" value="Cancel"></input>
              </form>
        </div>
     <!--apex:commandButton value="Accpet Invitaion" action="{!switch}" reRender="AccountTabPanel"/-->


 </apex:column> 
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

```
                        j$(document).ready(function(){
                            j$("#Submit").click(function() 
                                { 
                                var input = document.getElementById("ID").value;

                                 Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                                  '{!$RemoteAction.Publication_Tab_Controller.update_publication}',input,
                                  function(results, event)
                                  {
                                      console.log(result);
                                  }
                                );
                                });

                          });
                      </script>
```